# In php, why incrementing string 'Z' prints 'AA'?

Tags: php

If I try to run the following in PHP:

```
<?php
$a = 'Z';
echo ++$a;
```

It will surprisingly print `AA`.

Why it is so? What's the rationale behind that?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php "PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA'..."

Comment: From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php): PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl `$a = 'Z'; $a++;` turns `$a` into `'AA'`, while in C `a = 'Z'; a++;` turns a into `'['` (ASCII value of `'Z'` is `90`, ASCII value of `'['` is `91`).